# Sending Push Notification from Back end system to Azure Push Notification Hub

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

While sending the message to Azure Push Notification Hub, do I need to every time register the application ID?

Answer (score 0):

Application Id? Maybe you are talking about device token?
When you register your device on push notification hub  - you generate device token only 1-st time and register it on hub. Then you send notifications on this registration (but device token has expiration, and also regenerates in some cases (such as reinstall app), also registration on push notification hub has expiration(90 days). So any time you push notification - you should check - if exists registration on hub.

If application Id = gcm(android), certificate(ios) - you should register them only on creating notification hub.